# MongoDB stress test

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing a test for mongodb. 
The version of mongo is 2.4.9. And in the database I have more than 2.5 Millions of documents inserted in a collection like:

```
[{"_id": _id, "id" : _id, "row1": "0000-000000000-000000000-00", "meta" : "domainName", "type" : "domainType", "timestamp" : "01234646458", "relations" : { "direct" [], "indirect": ["domain1", "domain2"]}, "extension" : "net", "usage" : "intranet","extraValue":Math.random()}, ...]
```

The collection just now is indexed, and working good inserting the data, the problem occurs when I'm trying to randomly read the data from the database, with aprox. 100 threads searching a non-specific document each 2 seconds (Each 2 seconds a new operation starts). The operation is simple, is read a document and insert a new document linked (only by reference) with other document, the operations doesn't affect the randomically search. The first 255 minutes, work good, but after 25 minutes the connections are closed  or refushed. The cpu usage is normal and the network usage is normal too, with other database I didn't have the same problem. Exist some consideration in the moment to read data from mongo? Or maybe could be problem of the driver? Just now, the test is with node.js and mongo with the mongodb MongoClient driver.

Comment: You need to include more details. Are you properly pooling/ closing the connections? Have a look at `db.serverStatus().connections` while running your test.

Comment: > db.serverStatus().connections
`{ "current" : 7, "available" : 6546, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(2710345) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest checking if that issues is originating on the server or the client. On server you can check for following:

- MongoD logs for any evident issues being reported
- ulimits for the server - assuming your MongoD instance is running on a Linux (or a flavor of Unix) server.

On the client you can check for:

- If on Linux / Unix, check for ulimits
- Checks for pooled connections
- Does restart of the client application resolves the problem? If so, this would certainly look like a client issue, but making server checks will be useful just in case.